# Jetpack recomposition behavior

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

When state changes recomposition should fire. In code sample one state changes but recomposition doesn't fire but in code sample two state changes onButtonClick and recomposition fires.

How to make code sample one to recompose on state change?

1. Below code does not fire recomposition

```
@Composable
fun doSomething(){
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var shouldDo by remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }

    LaunchedEffect(context){
        scope.launch(Dispatchers.Default){
            //Fetch a data from dataSource
            //then change the state
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                shouldDo = true
            }
        }
    }
    //Process the data when @shouldDo state changes to true
    if(shouldDo){
        Log.e("=======================", "shouldDo: $shouldDo")
    }
}
```

2. But this code fire recomposition upon Button Click

```
@Composable
fun doSomeOtherThing() {
    var shouldDo by remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }
    if(shouldDo){
        Log.e("=======================", "shouldDo: $shouldDo")
    }
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
            onClick = {
                shouldDo = true
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Button")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your first code block works fine to me - I see the log. Both on Compose **1.1.1** and **1.2.0-alpha04**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to make code sample one to recompose on state change?

You should use a `SideEffect` to mutate state during first composition in order for these changes to take "effect" :

```
@Composable
fun doSomething() {
    var shouldDo by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    if (shouldDo) {
        Log.e("=======================", "shouldDo: $shouldDo")
    }

    SideEffect {
        shouldDo = true
    }
}
```

Further reading : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects

Comment: My problem is that I am changing the state form coroutine. Please see my edited code sample one.

Comment: Your updated code, which looks very different to the orginal code works? Also It would be more pragmatic to make the "data" the observed state, not a boolean flag, but again your updated code is incomplete. I'm confused - are you sure you don't have a XY problem here?